# function equalHeight , set a minimum Height to apply?

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, css-position, calculated-columns

I have tried everything, but without javascript I cannot achieve the **bad layout** my designer gave to me!!

> > As you can see I have the div **#backgr-box** that has to be absolute positioned with z-index to be properly behind the **#contenuto** (which holds the page content!!) 
> >     Now to solve the extensibilty trouble of **#backgr-box** I have the below code that works if the content of #contenuto is longer than the sidebar **#barra-laterale**  , but it is not ok in opposite case, see page: http://demo.liquidfactory.it/secondopolo/per-informarti

So how can I tell javascript to apply that calculation only over a minimum height of div sidebar **#barra-laterale** ??

Need help.. please!

```
function equalHeight(group) {
           tallest = 0;
           group.each(function() {
              thisHeight = $(this).height();
              if(thisHeight > tallest) {
                 tallest = thisHeight = $("#contenuto").height() - 380;
              }
           });
           group.height(tallest);
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
           equalHeight($(".column"));
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely with this line:

```
tallest = thisHeight = $("#contenuto").height() - 380;
```

Currently it is  setting both the variables `tallest` and `thisHeight` to the height of the content region minus 380 pixels. Change it to:

```
tallest = thisHeight;
```

And it will resize all the columns to the height of the tallest one.

**Edit**: It looks like your right-hand column actually consists of multiple columns  with a class of `.barra-laterale` in this case you may want to take another tack altogether:

```
// calculate the total height of the content are and sidebar
var contentHeight = $("#contenuto").height();
var sidebarHeight = 0;
$(".barra-laterale").each(function() { sidebarHeight += $(this).height(); })

if (sidebarHeight > contentHeight) {
    $("#contenuto").height(sidebarHeight);
} else {
    // extend the last sidebar column to cover the difference between the 
    // height of the content and the sum of the sidebar heights
    var lastSideBarHeight = $(".barra-laterale").last().height();
    var heightDifference = contentHeight - sidebarHeight; 
    $(".barra-laterale").last().height(lastSideBarHeight + heightDifference) 
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris and Tomalak! ehps.. it doesn't seem to work! But have a look, now I have added the id #barra-laterale to the long sidebar and consider that the first sidebar can be kept as a fixed height.. 380px! Could this help us? long page: http://demo.liquidfactory.it/secondopolo/bacheca/prova